# Redirect to download document page after Embedded signing

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using embedded signing with PHP as there on [DocuSignAPI embedded signing session redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764705/docusignapi-embedded-signing-session-redirect-url)

When i am redirecting signer to Signing URL. After signing the Signer is redirected to Return URL.
Instead i want signer to redirect to Docusign Page with Download Document button.
[image]

Also the signer is not getting mails with the signed document.

Is it possible in Sandbox mode?

I have done settings in Admin panel for sending mails after signing 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In embedded signing, it is NOT possible for the signer to be redirected to Docusign Page with Download Document button.

Alternatively, you can redirect the Signer to your APP and create a page with the "Download Document" button. Upon clicking the button your app can call the [getEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/) api and download the document.

Make sure your app authenticates the signer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
In which way the Signer is redirected to that download document Page?

As i have seen websites redirecting to that page and which is having similar process flow as mine : ie
Fill form from my website then redirecting to docusign to sign the document without any login and then redirecting to download document Page.
Thanks in advance